# Passing an array as a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was wondering if its possible to pass a value of an array as a value inside a tag? For example, the following piece of code:

```
var itemfeed = this.state.jsonData.map((item,i) => {
  return(
    <View key={i}>
      <TouchableHighlight val = {this.state.dataarray[i]} onPress={() => this.toggleExpanded2(i)}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>{item.date}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.dataarray[i]} align="center">
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text>{item.Desc}</Text>
        </View>
      </Collapsible>
    </View>             
  );
```

This is the togglefunction:

```
toggleExpanded2(i) {
  var newarr = this.state.dataarray;
  newarr[i] = !this.state.dataarray[i];

  this.setState({
    dataarray:newarr
  })
  this.setState({ collapsed: this.state.dataarray[i] });
  console.log("index" + i + "value"+ this.state.dataarray[i]+ "collapsed"+ this.state.collapsed);
}
```

maps items to a view element. I am trying to pass a value of an array into the *collapsed* property as a value where collapsed is a boolean value. However, it does not appear to be working. I know that the values for the arrays are indeed defined. What I am trying to do is make it so that when the user clicks on the view, the element will show and stay there until the user decides to tap it and close it again. Whether it shows or not depends on the value of *collapsed*.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know, you should always format your code into an easy-to-read format. It helps both you and us understand the program and spot bugs. I've cleaned it up for you this time but keep it in mind if you ask future questions :)

Comment: apologies ill keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not treat `setState()` as a synchronous operation**, as it may not be:

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

---

Instead of reading `this.state` right after calling `this.setState()`, rely on your local mutated new state, e.g.:

```
toggleExpanded2(i) {
  var newarr = this.state.dataarray.slice(0); // Create a shallow copy of `this.state.dataarray`, treating the state as immutable
  newarr[i] = !newarr[i];

  var newCollapsed = !newarr[i];

  this.setState({
    dataarray: newarr,
    collapsed: newCollapsed
  });

  console.log("index" + i + "value"+ newarr[i]+ "collapsed"+ newCollapsed);
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work :(.  Every time I click, it doesn't toggle it just sits there. Can I assign a value to collapsed in the fashion that I did?

Comment: You can't necessarily, since there's no way of knowing whether the state has already been updated at this point. Why do you have to?

Comment: I need each collapsible row to be unique in order to open them and make them stay open.  Looking back on it I don't think i need to set the state of collapsible in the toggle function as I am determining the state of collapsible here:<Collapsible collapsed={this.state.dataarray[i]} align="center">. But I still can't get the bar to close and open. It makes me think that there might be something in the assignment of collapsed.

Comment: If I have don't have a unique value for collapsible, then all of them will open and close and the same time at the click of any element. I do not want this. I want them to be open one at a time and for them to stay open, which is why I was placing an array value inside collapsed

Comment: Nvm I solved it using your method. I had to have the collapsible panel in its own class and than pass the values as props to that specific panel class. Some thing very similar to this setup here: http://moduscreate.com/expanding-and-collapsing-elements-using-animations-in-react-native/.